# UITableViewCells grouped and accordion

Tags: core-data, uitableview, accordion

I would like to make something like this using CoreData:

[UITableViewCell with accordion](http://cl.ly/EAhj)

is there anyone who could help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get this http://cl.ly/EFZ9 but i would like to merge the rows with the same day in one row.

Comment: I meant in terms of code. The image just shows the UI, not the core data part. What exactly is the problem? What does not work?

Comment: The image showing what I get using NSFetchedResultsController, I would like to merge two rows with the same day on a single row. when I tap on the merged row I would like to show subrows with the same day.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize, your question is that you would like to have one row for each **date** and that additional rows should appear after tapping such a row and there is **more than one item** for that date. Your fetched results controller now gives you just one row per item, your section header is the month.

As you have month section headers, I suppose you are already using transient properties. Maybe one approach is to create another transient property for the date. You could then check for the number of items on that date in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: yes I'm using transient properties. could you give me an example for the cellForRowsAtIndexPath method? thanks.

Comment: Could you give me an example please?

Comment: I think an example would go beyond the scope of this platform. In short, you have to modify the table view's datasource. Check out the Apple sample code that has collapsable sections: [Table View Animation and Gestures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html)